# I made an APP using xcode but I cant pay nor

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've finished the APP and need to pay and upload it to the 'App Store' (first time), I logged in to the developer.apple.com as you can see in picture1 and looked for 'Certifications, ID's and Profiles' as in YouTube but I couldn't find as a link.

Can someone help?

Thanks

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gvjs.png)

Comment: you need to subscribe to apple developer membership.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: Go to this page: https://developer.apple.com/enroll/ here you can enroll in the Apple Developer Program.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll follow these and get back to you!,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about developer accounts.